# Problems with drawing amcharts in offline

Tags: javascript, ios, charts, offline, amcharts

I'd like to draw amcharts in offline. It works fine in offline already but I got some **problems with scrollbar grips - they are not drawned** because all images stored at `http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/` and the property `chart.pathToImages` is defined to this path.
I see only one way to solve my **problem** :

1. find out what's the name of grip's icon
2. create my own icon with the same name
3. put it into my local folder
4. change property `chart.pathToImages` setting it to my folder path.

Can somebody help me with first task in the list?

PS I got one image from standart amcharts folder: http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/star.gif
and i've tried some variations for scrollbar grips, but have no results atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem!
I just opened `amcharts.js` and CTRL+F'ed it with "gif" and it returned me followed names:
dragIcon.gif
dragIconH.gif
which are exactly what i've been looking for.

PS. I'm working on an iOS application which can draw amcharts in offline, so for do this I downloaded the `amcharts.js` and added it to my project, then I created my `html` file and added into it following string in purpose of import `amcharts.js` library

```
<script src="amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then I loaded my `html` into the UIWebView:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; //URL representation of main project bundle

NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chart" ofType:@"html"];
NSError *error;
NSString *htmlStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlStr , [self getJSONStringFromDict:dataDict] , baseUrl]; // i do this for insert JSONdata and baseURL into my HTML (see below)
[self loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:baseUrl];
```

baseURL is very important in case you want to use local files in your `html`
that's why `src="amcharts.js"` works fine.

And finally! What about my scrollbar grips?
As I mentioned before, I downloaded the file `dargIcon.gif` and added it to my project (same I did with `amcharts.js`), then I replaced

`chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/"`

with `chart.pathToImages = "%@";`
%@ will be replaced with my baseURL (see code above)

Problem solved. Hope this helps somebody.